# Proving Bonferroni's Inequality.

Tags: probability

[image: Prove the probability of n events intersecting is greater than or equal to the sum of the probability of each individual event minus (n - l)]

I'm trying to write a proof for this, but I don't know how to get started.

Would proof by induction be the easiest way?

If you could break it down into general steps I could wrap my head around, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: The term $(n-1)$ does seem to suggest induction.

Comment: Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2102774/show-pa-cap-b-geq-papb-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using finite subadditivity of probability, we have

$1 - \mathbb{P}\left( {\bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^n {{E_i}} } \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( {{{\left( {\bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^n {{E_i}} } \right)}^C}} \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( {\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n {E_i^C} } \right) \leqslant \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\mathbb{P}\left( {E_i^C} \right)}  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left( {1 - \mathbb{P}\left( {{E_i}} \right)} \right)}  = n - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\mathbb{P}\left( {{E_i}} \right)} $

which implies $\mathbb{P}\left( {\bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^n {{E_i}} } \right) \geqslant 1 - n + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\mathbb{P}\left( {{E_i}} \right)}  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\mathbb{P}\left( {{E_i}} \right)}  - \left( {n - 1} \right)$