# How can I show that $P(A \cap B) \gt P(A) + P(B) - 1$

Tags: probability, inequality

How can I show that $P(A \cap B) \gt P(A) + P(B) - 1$

I know that
$P(A \cap B)= P(A)P(B)$

But I don't see how that can help me get to that inequality.
Can someone give me a hint on how to start this?

Comment: $P(A \cap B) = P(A)\cap P(B)$ doesn't make sense. $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are numbers so there is no idea of their intersection in the probabilistic sense.

Comment: Are these events independent???

Comment: @ncmathsadist that is all I am given. There is nothing more to the question.I am having a hard time trying to figure it out

Comment: If you let $A=B$ be an event that is always true you get $1>1$.

Comment: use $B=A'$ to get $0\gt0$

Comment: See also: [Show $P(A\cap B)\geq P(A)+P(B)-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2102774). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24P(A%20%5Ccap%20B)%20%5Cgt%20P(A)%20%2B%20P(B)%20-%201%24&p=1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The $>$ sign should change to $\ge$ to make sense. This is because
$$P(A\cup B)\le 1$$
$$P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)\le 1$$
$$P(A)+P(B)-1\le P(A\cap B)$$

Answer (score 7):

It's not true as stated, but with $\ge$ instead of $>$ it would be true.
Note that $$ P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = P(A \cup B) \le 1$$

Answer (score 5):

The inequality is not correct, for example, let $A$ be the event that you get a head and $B$ be the even that you get a tail.

$$P(A \cap B)=0$$

$$P(A)+P(B)-1=0$$

$$0> 0$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Oh I see so the inequality should be equal or greater not just greater. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, as proven by msm.

Comment: Also, $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ only holds when you have independence of events.

Answer (score 2):

$$P(A\cap B)-P(A)-P(B)+1=P(A)P(B)-P(A)-P(B)+1=$$
$$=\left(1-P(A)\right)\left(1-P(B)\right)\geq0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$P(A\cup B) =P(A) +P(B) - P(A\cap B)$$

$$P(S)=1 \ge P(A \cup B)$$

$$P(A∩B) \le P(A) + P(B) - 1 $$